# How can I create a Facebook app that only people I give the link to can use? Or must be on a list?

Tags: facebook, privacy, developer-tools

I have created an app but there is private information that I do not want the general public to have access to. This is a calendar app. I would like to have this where only specific people can access the calendar app. Is this possible and if so, how do I accomplish this as this is the first app I have created? I have seen a post about having their Facebook user ID's in a database but how do I connect that database to my app? Lost

Answer (score 0):

If you're using their email, and they happen to use such email to log into facebook, then you would be able to let them use your app ONLY if they are on a list on your server or whatever. I would start by checking out this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4